# MUI theme with different palette mode for nested components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, theming

### I have:

- A main theme with **DARK** mode.
- -> A card-like component with **LIGHT** mode (because it has light background).
- ->-> Some Selects in the card-like component, and I want the MENU to be **DARK** mode (but the label etc should be **LIGHT** mode).

I searched through theming, sx, styled etc. Nada.
I tried to create a HoC which wraps a component with Theme provider and places it here: Select -> MenuProps -> ListProps -> component: createThemedComponent(theme, MenuList).

This is already ugly.

Even uglier is that the bg color depends on the Paper component, so you should pass themed component to the Paper props as well.

And even more ugly is that it doesn't work either, so I figured out that MenuProps can receive `component` prop as well passing it down to Popover to Modal, but... For some reason it doesn't work properly, even if it's not visible it's actually present in the DOM and it blocks any interactions on the page.

You could say "oh, just figure out how to pass a custom component to the Modal properly", yeah, but the point is that to do what I wanted I had to go down to the Hell and I've spent unnecessary amount of time figuring out how to do it.

Solution: I will use `styleOverrides` for MenuList in the theme for the card-like component, styling it *manually*.
This means I have to look-up the styles applied to the **DARK** mode Menus and copypaste them, obviously it's not guaranteed it will be the same.

### Question:

Is there a helper to create styles for MUI component based on the provided theme?

OR

Is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your component with theme provider and mutate the `mode` prop:

```js
<ThemeProvider theme={(outerTheme) => createTheme({ ...outerTheme, palette: { mode: 'dark' } })}>
  <NestedComponent />
</ThemeProvider>
```

Please refer to [default theme shape](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/default-theme/) from official MUI docs.